# API calls work on localhost but not on 127.0 API

Tags: android, api, localhost, android-volley

I am in the process of writing an Android app and am currently working on sending a POST request to an existing API that is meant to authorize users. When I start my express server on my local machine and attempt to authorize users via command line it works, however on Android you cannot access the localhost from the emulator so I'm forced to start an http server. However when I try to call this new IP address I can no longer successfully call the companies API. I'm curious if there's a workaround or a way I can connect to this API from my Android emulator without having to run my server only on localhost.

My current Android code using the Volley library to make API calls

```
String url ="http://localhost:3000/users/authorize";

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email",mEmail);
                    params.put("password",mPassword);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Command line calls to the localhost work fine! But when I switch the string URL to my http server ip address I can no longer successfully connect to my API and authorize users! Any help or ideas?

Edit: I've discovered the answer. In order to connect to your computers localhost from an Android emulator you have to use the IP 10.0.2.2. [link](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-run-an-android-app-against-a-localhost-api) here.

Comment: you can't access local host in emulator ?

Comment: @Shubhank Thank you! I found this [link](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-run-an-android-app-against-a-localhost-api) and it works fine now.

Comment: great. you should check if there is similar question already on stack and **if not** go ahead and answer your own question.

Comment: @Shubhank You are right about that. I'll be sure to post my answer.